# Mirror parts of screen to external monitor

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, display

I'd like to mirror/clone separate parts of my iMac screen to smaller external displays.

For me the best solution would be to draw a frame on top of the iMac display and let that special frame show up on a smaller external display.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: would screen sharing work for that?

Comment: I've never seen anything that can do this. You can ADD a screen to the Mac but I am unsure if this is even possible. However wiser people than me may know of something...

Answer (score 1):

There are tools for doing this which are visual aids like zooming and following the mouse around, maybe they might work?